# Bind9 DNS Setup

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I have my network set up like this:

[image]

My question: what is the best approach for setting DNS on this network so that all host (H1, H2 and H3) can resolve each other? It is enough to just have NS1 as primary DNS for all hosts? Or i also need to setup secondary NS2 which will resolve H2 and H3 separately so NS1 will only have record for NS2 and H1? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the yellow box that says `192.168.0.1/24` should say `192.168.1.0/24`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have IP routing working correctly between all the hosts, I see no problem in having all the host records set up on NS1 / R1 nameserver.